# Why is there a blue square on top of the 2Q9 airport symbol?

Tags: airport, aeronautical-charts

What is up with the sectional symbol for Dyer (2Q9)?  Why is there a blue square on top of it?

[image: Dyer (2Q9) airport symbol is overlaid with a blue square with a beige color inside]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## The blue square is the symbol for the Dyer DME

[image: VFR Sectional Chart legend showing a blue square as the DME symbol]

[image: Excerpt of San Francisco sectional chart with full Dyer DME radio block visible]

### Why?

The discontinuity is because Dyer is extremely close to the intersection of the San Francisco and Las Vegas sectionals, and the AirNav/Avare software probably discarded that inch of pixels when it merged the two charts.

For reference, here's where Dyer is on the Las Vegas sectional.

[image: Las Vegas Sectional, with a point just off the edge of the chart highlighted]

Comment: I did not know this is how they depicted DMEs on unpaved airports. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know why AirNav and Avare don't display the DME info box and have discontinuities in that area?

Comment: @Zaz - Because it's where two charts meet.  See updated answer.

Comment: Wow. I always assumed the FAA had accounted for electronic maps and released a properly stitched-together version. I guess not.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [airnav.com](https://www.airnav.com/airport/2Q9) website, on the far right-hand side of the page titled "Sectional Chart" click the picture.  This will take you to a much larger image of the Sectional Chart showing  Dyer (2Q9).

[image]

**Then click on the "blue square" directly over the airport symbol:**

[image]

**and you will see the airport information below on the left side of the page: (this extra information page overlaps the Dyer Airport (2Q9) symbol on the Sectional)**

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the detailed instructions as I always like to be taught how to find information for myself.  But, I'm sorry, what has that got to do with the blue square?  All the other airports also have information boxes, but they don't show up as squares that obscure the entire airport.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have said the big transparent square with blue border. Your answer was not wasted, however, as I did not know you could use AirNav like that. +1